# Use C++-slot in QML which returns type in namespace

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, moc

I first want to mention that the following worked fine up to Qt 5.0.0 beta 1 (maybe beta 2 and RC too, don't know), but fails in Qt 5.0.0 final release version. I only want to refer to the results seen in Qt 5.0.0 final release version. So most probably this has something to do with recent changes in Qt5.

On C++ side I have a set of classes (QObject-derived) in a namespace (which is optionally triggered with compiler flags; the classes are in a separate library and the library leaves the usage of a namespace as an option to the user of the library). A class, here `Game`, might look like this (excerpt):

```
OAE_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

// forward-declarations:
class Player;    // Player is just another class in the same library

class Game : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Game(...);

public slots:
    Player *player() const;  // <-- the quesion is about such slots
};

OAE_END_NAMESPACE
```

The macros `OAE_BEGIN/END_NAMESPACE` expand to either `namespace OAE_NAMESPACE {` ... `}` or nothing, in the same way Qt does it in `<qglobal.h>`, just "QT" replaced with "OAE" in the macro names:

```
#ifndef OAE_NAMESPACE

# define OAE_PREPEND_NAMESPACE(name) ::name
# define OAE_USE_NAMESPACE
# define OAE_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
# define OAE_END_NAMESPACE
# define OAE_BEGIN_INCLUDE_NAMESPACE
# define OAE_END_INCLUDE_NAMESPACE
# define OAE_BEGIN_MOC_NAMESPACE
# define OAE_END_MOC_NAMESPACE
# define OAE_FORWARD_DECLARE_CLASS(name) class name;
# define OAE_FORWARD_DECLARE_STRUCT(name) struct name;
# define OAE_MANGLE_NAMESPACE(name) name

#else /* user namespace */

# define OAE_PREPEND_NAMESPACE(name) ::OAE_NAMESPACE::name
# define OAE_USE_NAMESPACE using namespace ::OAE_NAMESPACE;
# define OAE_BEGIN_NAMESPACE namespace OAE_NAMESPACE {
# define OAE_END_NAMESPACE }
# define OAE_BEGIN_INCLUDE_NAMESPACE }
# define OAE_END_INCLUDE_NAMESPACE namespace OAE_NAMESPACE {
# define OAE_BEGIN_MOC_NAMESPACE OAE_USE_NAMESPACE
# define OAE_END_MOC_NAMESPACE
# define OAE_FORWARD_DECLARE_CLASS(name) \
    OAE_BEGIN_NAMESPACE class name; OAE_END_NAMESPACE \
    using OAE_PREPEND_NAMESPACE(name);

# define OAE_FORWARD_DECLARE_STRUCT(name) \
    OAE_BEGIN_NAMESPACE struct name; OAE_END_NAMESPACE \
    using OAE_PREPEND_NAMESPACE(name);

# define OAE_MANGLE_NAMESPACE0(x) x
# define OAE_MANGLE_NAMESPACE1(a, b) a##_##b
# define OAE_MANGLE_NAMESPACE2(a, b) OAE_MANGLE_NAMESPACE1(a,b)
# define OAE_MANGLE_NAMESPACE(name) OAE_MANGLE_NAMESPACE2( \
        OAE_MANGLE_NAMESPACE0(name), OAE_MANGLE_NAMESPACE0(OAE_NAMESPACE))

namespace OAE_NAMESPACE {}

# ifndef OAE_BOOTSTRAPPED
# ifndef OAE_NO_USING_NAMESPACE
   /*
    This expands to a "using OAE_NAMESPACE" also in _header files_.
    It is the only way the feature can be used without too much
    pain, but if people _really_ do not want it they can add
    DEFINES += OAE_NO_USING_NAMESPACE to their .pro files.
    */
   OAE_USE_NAMESPACE
# endif
# endif

#endif /* user namespace */
```

In the following, when saying "enabling the namespace", I mean I declared the macro `OAE_NAMESPACE`, in this case with the value `oae`.

Among others, I access instances of this class and the `Player` class as returned by `player()` from within QML for the user interface of my application. For this, I register the classes as follows:

```
qmlRegisterType<Game>();
qmlRegisterType<Player>();
```

I provide the QML frontend a pointer to an instance of a `Game`, called `theGame` within QML:

```
view.engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("theGame",
        QVariant::fromValue<Game*>(game));
```

Within QML, I use this as usual. A small example should print a pointer address of the `player()`:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 100; height: 100
    Component.onCompleted: console.log(theGame.player())
}
```

I get the following results, depending on whether I set a `OAE_NAMESPACE` or not (by the way: I use the same setting for both the library and the application using it):

- When **disabling the namespace**, everything works as expected and
  QML prints me the pointer:

  ```
  Player(0x10b4ae0)
  ```
- When **enabling the namespace** (and `using` it in the C++ code using
  the library, so I don't change the code at all), QML fails to
  understand the return type of `Game::player()`:

  ```
  Error: Unknown method return type: Player*
  ```
- When **changing the return type** of `Game::player()` to
  `oae::Player*`, everything works fine again:

  ```
  oae::Player(0x10b4ae0)
  ```

My conclusion so far is that `moc` doesn't consider the namespace I put around the class. My first guess was: Hey, `moc` doesn't know that I define the namespace when calling `g++`, which is what I do in the .pro file:

```
DEFINES += OAE_NAMESPACE=oae
```

However, when changing the return type to `OAE_NAMESPACE::Player*`, it still works, so moc *does* know of the `OAE_NAMESPACE` macro, but it doesn't either expand the `OAE_BEGIN/END_NAMESPACE` macros or it doesn't parse namespaces at all anymore.

`moc` produces the following "stringdata" for `Player * Game::player() const` which containes the method's return type:

- When **disabling the namespace** and using the return type `Player*`:

  ```
  "player\0Player*\0"
  ```
- When **enabling the namespace** and using the return type `Player*`:

  ```
  "player\0Player*\0"
  ```
- When **enabling the namespace** and using the return type `OAE_NAMESPACE::Player*`:

  ```
  "player\0oae::Player*\0"
  ```

On the other side, `moc` prepends class names as returned by `QMetaObject::className()` with the namespace if enabled.

My conclusion now is that I *could* fix this by writing `OAE_NAMESPACE::ClassName` instead of `ClassName` whenever using these types in the signatures of QObject meta methods. (Well, there is the better macro `OAE_PREPEND_NAMESPACE`). Since this would look horrible in the code, and to me it even seems wrong because the method *already is in the namespace*, **is there a better solution?**

Now there also is `OAE_BEGIN/END_MOC_NAMESPACE` (analogous to `QT_BEGIN/END_MOC_NAMESPACE`), ***so maybe I need those anywhere***? I don't know where/how they are used in Qt, so I should use them accordingly in my library, since I want to use the same optional namespace feature as Qt does.

Comment: I'll add some information on what code moc produced (how the signature of the slot was parsed, for example).

Comment: Does using qmlRegisterType<> with namespace-qualified typename change anything?

Comment: @mlvjr Thanks for your hint, but I already tried this. Actually, this shouldn't change anything, since that's a C++ type specifier but this is about how `moc` parses the header file. It doesn't detect that `Player` within the namespace actually refers the class `oae::Player` when used outside of the namespace. Also I believe that this behavior was different in Qt 5.0.0 alpha and beta1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did it really worked in 5.0.0a?

I browsed through Qt 5.0.0 source code and looked where methods are parsed, especially the return type (fyi, 5.0.0\qtbase\src\tools\moc\moc.cpp:L160) and there are no namespace check (neither on the arguments, so `player(Player* p)` won't work either).
Whereas, it's done for the class def (5.0.0\qtbase\src\tools\moc\moc.cpp:L620 & L635)

I think "we" can call this a bug (or an oversight)

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I'll double-check this tomorrow. Of course the mistake can be on my side, I don't want to exclude this possibility ;)

Comment: Well, it seems *not* to work in Qt 5.0.0 beta1, too. I just retried it. Strange that I remembered it worked. Thank you for putting your time into finding this stuff in the moc code and congratulations for your bounty points!